# Proving not path-connected of a connected set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

$\textbf{Question:}$ Let $A$ be The deleted infinite broom and let $B$ be the segment $[0.5,1]x{0}$. Prove that $A\cup B$ is not path-connected.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ For this, I tried to show it's impossible find a path such that $(0,0)$ can be joined to $(1,0)$. However, I don't get it, and I don't know if this way is the most straightforward...

I'll grateful with your help.

$\textbf{NOTES:}$ I'm considering $A$ and $B$ with the induced topology by $R^2$.

This is the definition that I have about The deleted infinite broom: For each integer $n > 0$, let $L_n$ be the line segment in $R^2$ joining the origin $(0,0)$ to the point $(1, \frac{1}{n})$. $A$ would be $\cup L_n \cup (0,1)$

Comment: Define deleted infinite broom?  I looked on WIki and only found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_broom

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your overall plan is good, it just needs execution.

Hint: Suppose you had a path $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_x(t),\gamma_y(t))$ such that $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$ and $\gamma(1)=(1,0)$.

Now let $t_0 = \sup \{ t \mid \gamma_x(t) \le \frac13\}$. What can you say about $\gamma(t_0)$? And what can you then say about $\gamma(t)$ for $t>t_0$?

Comment: It only occurs to me that $\gamma (t_0)$ and $\gamma (t)$ for $t<t_0$ will be in some $L_n$...

Comment: @JELV: The interesting part is $t > t_0$, where by definition $\gamma_x(t)>\frac13$.

Comment: I don't understand your idea, I don't find some implcation...I suppose that  I must study the topics again...

Comment: @JELV: At $t_0$ you have $\gamma_x(t_0)=\frac13$ and $\gamma_y(t_0)/\gamma_x(t_0)=1/n$ for some integer $n$. You want, in particular $\gamma_y(1)/\gamma_x(1) = 0$. Now use the intermediate value theorem to find a contradiction ...

Comment: Now all is clear for me! I'm sorry if I was a little slow. Thank you a lot!